# How to migrate a .NET4 solution to .NET Core 3?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

I did the following fork: https://github.com/MaherJendoubi/ClearCanvas and
I cloned the following project https://github.com/ClearCanvas/ReferencedAssemblies in order to create a hard link using the following command from ClearCanvas directory: `mklink ReferencedAssemblies ..\ReferencedAssemblies`.
I opened ImageViewer.sln and I targeted all 60 projects to the .NET 4.7.2, it compiles and runs without any issue like with .NET 4. In order to execute the solution, you have to choose ClearCanvas.Desktop.Executable as a startup project.
Then, I used the following tool : https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017
through the following command : `dotnet-migrate-2017 wizard "Path to ImageViewer.sln"`. But before targeting .NET Core 3, I compiled the project but it fails. I am wondering if it is the right strategy to migrate or not? Would you please help me with compiling the project?
I will try to give as much information as I can to find a solution to this problem. I put all the errors here :https://gist.github.com/MaherJendoubi/70d392a501400df90f0d3e59b90f91cf

I committed my modifications at the migration branch : https://github.com/MaherJendoubi/ClearCanvas/tree/migration

I am using the last preview of VS2019.

dotnet --version

3.0.100-preview4-010379

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,

Maher.

Comment: The errors indicate that the reference to NUnit wasn't found. Could you please verify that the nunit.framework.dll is indeed found in this path: 
https://github.com/MaherJendoubi/ClearCanvas/blob/migration/Common/ClearCanvas.Common.csproj#L76

I'm guessing you need to carefully follow the instructions to place the ReferencedAssemblies next to the repo so that the link (relative path) works fine.

Comment: The conversion tool only did an initial part, you need to manually revisit everything, and ideally convert to a PackageReference to reference NUnit. Like this:
    `<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.11.0" />`

Comment: With regards to your larger plan to port it to .NET Core, ImageViewer is not going to be portable to .NET Core at this point without very major work. It's got a bunch of System.Graphics stuff in there for image manipulation, not to mention WinForms and 3rd party dlls like DotNetMagic which are targetted at older versions of the framework and the source code for DotNetMagic does not seem to be available.